# How to run application in cmd.exe with Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup

Say I want to install an `app.exe` with Inno Setup, but when the installation is done, I want the program to run

```
cmd /k app.exe
```

instead of just `app.exe`.

Currently I have:

```
Filename: "cmd /k {app}\app.exe"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,app}"; \
    Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent runascurrentuser
```

But of course this complains about cannot find the file with the given file name. What should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The command parameters have to go to a separate parameter `Parameters`. See the documentation for the [`[Run]` section](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection).
2. You have to surround the path to the application with double-quotes as the path may contain a space (and typically does: `Program Files`). And you need to [double the double-quotes](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=params).
3. Use the [`{cmd}` constant](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts&anchor=cmd) instead of an explicit reference to the `cmd.exe`.

```
Filename: "{cmd}"; Parameters: "/c ""{app}\app.exe"""; \
    Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,app}"; \
    Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent runascurrentuser
```

*I assume that use of the `/k` was for debugging only. As with it the `cmd` never finish. For production use, you need `/c` instead.*